# Configure RDP on Windows 2008R2 with Static IP from ISP

Tags: networking, dns

I have static IP given by my ISP for my Windows Server 2008 R2 and now in this. I wan to configure RDP to connect to the server from remote location with Internet connectivity.

I have two NIC available on server and on NIC ISP has assign the IPs.
PLease find IP addresses on the server.

### Windows IP Configuration

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXServer
Primary Dns Suffix . . . . . . . : 
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-F2-E9-34-72-C7
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 40-F2-E9-34-72-C8
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::fd7e:fb78:1032:1af9%11(Preferred) 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 238305461
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-8D-20-39-40-F2-E9-34-72-C8
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 202.83.21.12
202.83.20.101
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BA207A81-9D81-4043-8AC2-2797054D28B5}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{7A11F7EA-BD3C-4B0B-9685-6EFEE0D34F8F}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:2083:3049:3f57:fffd(Preferred) 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2083:3049:3f57:fffd%16(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

---

Now i want to configure RDP I tried every other way it is not going through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static doesn't mean public. 192.168.0.2 is private IP address although it can be static. So from outside world, your computer will be unavailable. Btw, i think that this question should go to https://serverfault.com/ or some other stack exchange site.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your prompt response. So if i understood correctly. I can able to ping Static IP from Internet when i try to RDP  on it. It is failing. So still you think that Static IP may not right solution for this configuration.  Please advice.

Comment: Static IP = IP address, which is not changing in time. You know, that IP address you have today is the address, you will have tomorrow.

Dynamic IP = IP address you have assigned by DHCP server (or something like that). Today it can be 192.168.0.2, tomorrow 192.168.0.98 ... 

Private IP = IP addr. you have on LAN, connection to internet is made via some routing device (NAT, masquerade)
Public IP = Address that is visible for whole world, even if they are not in your LAN segment.

If you want your RDP available outside, you need to have public IP address or port forwarding (DNAT).